# Can you rollback a query in state 'committing alter table to storage engine'

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

We've got an InnoDB table with 70 million rows, and we have been trying to run an alter table statement to modify and add a couple of columns. The query seems to have altered the table, and is now in the state of 'committing alter table to storage engine'.

```
START TRANSACTION;
ALTER TABLE table
  MODIFY COLUMN column1 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  MODIFY COLUMN column2 tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  ADD COLUMN column3 int(11),
  ADD COLUMN column4 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  ADD COLUMN column5 varchar(255);
COMMIT;
```

This has been running overnight, and is at 19 hours at the current time. We do not have the performance schema enabled so cannot look at an estimated time of completion. My concern lies as to what the query is doing and whether the query will rollback if killed. I have seen other questions relate to queries that are stuck in copying to tmp tables, or awaiting a table lock. However I cannot find anything about being stuck while the alter table is committing.

Is it safe to kill a query in this state, and if the query is killed, will it rollback successfully?

The server is running MariaDB 10.2

Comment: 2 important questions: 1) what did the MODIFY do (set not null? set default value? change type?) and 2) is the table still in use? It could simply be waiting to get a lock to commit.

Comment: 1) The modifies were setting the default value on column1, and the not null & default value on column 2. 2) This was the only query happening overnight on the table. According to this link (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/general-thread-states.html) The alter table should have already happened, and it's just taking a long time on the commit

Comment: Ok I can only answer this: "*My concern lies as to what the query is doing*" as far as I know, your `ALTER` did an in-place table rebuild (check [InnoDB Online DDL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/online-ddl-overview/) and [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html#innodb-online-ddl-summary-grid)). It's either waiting for a lock to commit (but probably not since you're saying the table is not in use) or it's just taking a long time to save the new version of the table with 70 millions rows...

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cannot-roll-back.html):

> Some statements cannot be rolled back. In general, these include data definition language (DDL) statements, such as those that create or drop databases, those that create, drop, or alter tables or stored routines.
>
> You should design your transactions not to include such statements. If you issue a statement early in a transaction that cannot be rolled back, and then another statement later fails, the full effect of the transaction cannot be rolled back in such cases by issuing a ROLLBACK statement.

Comment: While the post states that the ALTER TABLE is a DDL statement and would therefore not be able to be rolled back, as the statement is not yet complete, would it just leave the table in a corrupted state? Or is it still possible to rollback until the alter table is complete?

Answer (score 2):

I implemented the ALGORITHM=INPLACE and LOCK=NONE for InnoDB in MySQL 5.6.
Depending on the previous table definition, this operation could imply ALGORITHM=INPLACE, or it could fall back to ALGORITHM=COPY.
Starting with MariaDB 10.3 ([MDEV-11369](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11369)), ADD COLUMN would be instantaneous; before that, the table would have to be rebuilt. (The syntax ALGORITHM=INPLACE is very misleading.)
Starting with MariaDB 10.2.13 and 10.3.5 ([MDEV-11415](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11415)), ALGORITHM=COPY will no longer write undo log records for the individual rows, and the rollback (in case of client disconnect or killed server) should be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

As the `ALTER TABLE` is a DDL statement, [it causes an implicit commit](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sql-statements-that-cause-an-implicit-commit/) when it is executed. This means that it cannot be rolled back but interrupting the DDL (by killing the connection) will cause the already applied changes to be rolled back in a controlled manner.

Given that you are using the default `ALTER TABLE` operation (no [`ALGORITHM`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/alter-table/#algorithm-when-does-alter-table-copy-all-data) defined), cancelling it should be relatively fast as all it has to do, at least according to my knowledge, is to discard the new copy of the table.